# Pull messages from the last two hours?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, chat

I have made a simple chat system. I want only to pull the last two ours of messages from the database instead of the complete database. Can someone show me how this can be done? Thanks!

Code:

```
    if  (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        $userId = $_SESSION['id'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        $userLabel = $_SESSION['nickname'];
    }

    $connect = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "root");
    mysqli_select_db($connect, "root"); 
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM chat ORDER by id DESC");

    while ($extract = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        if ($extract['name'] == 'admin1') {
            $color = '#D00003';
        }
        else if ($extract['name'] == 'admin2') {
            $color = '#7E0002';
        }
        else {
            $color = '#FFFFFF';
        }

        if ($extract['name'] == $userLabel) {
            echo "
            <div class='usermessage'>
                <div class='mheader'>
                    <h2 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['time'] . "</h2>
                    <h3 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['name'] . "</h3>
                </div>
                <p>" . $extract['message'] . "</p>
            </div>";
        }
        else {
            echo "
            <div class='message'>
                <div class='mheader'>
                    <h2 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['time'] . "</h2>
                    <h3 style='color:".$color."'>" . $extract['name'] . "</h3>
                </div>
                <p>" . $extract['message'] . "</p>
            </div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use SQL [`date_sub`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat`
WHERE `time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
ORDER by `id` DESC
```

Comment: Just wanted to post this exact same, this is the right answer :)

Comment: Don't forget to add a source

Comment: This gives me "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean"

I suspect this is because the mysqli_fetch_assoc() is expecting to return something? What could be a workaround?

Comment: Try again, please, updated answer. If willn't help, write error which you will get

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this...

```
SELECT * FROM chat 
where
    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 120 MINUTE) <= date_col;
ORDER by id DESC
```

Check out official documentation for more information http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Two hours are 120 minutes ;)

Comment: This gives me "Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean"

I suspect this is because the mysqli_fetch_assoc() is expecting to return something? What could be a workaround?